# What type of clause is the given sentence?

Tags: sentence, clauses, complex-sentences

> Is the sentence "Then the staff assembled the units." a dependent or an independent clause?

Well, according to me, since there is subordinate conjunction "Then" in the sentence with no other sentence, so, therefore, it should be a dependent clause.
And also it kinda sounds incomplete when we speak out loud. :)

But my book says that its the main clause or independent clause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It makes sense by itself. It has subject, *The staff*; it has verb, *assembled* and it has predicate, *the units, then.* So, it is an independent clause.

Comment: Okay... Just one more doubt... Is "Then" subordinate conjunction?

Comment: *Then* can be used as a subordinating conjunction: "We ate lunch, then went out to play tennis.*

Comment: Please bear in mind that a single simple sentence is one clause and therefore is neither dependent or independent. Then is not a subordinating conjunction there at all. It's an adverb: when they did it.

Comment: Single sentences [are independent clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause).

Comment: @mama They may be but is there any point saying unless there are two clauses?

Comment: Yes, when that is the question that was asked. Simple logic. Not for everyone, though.

Comment: It's not a clause at all, but a preposition phrase. "Then" is not a conjunction, but a temporal preposition, which here has a declarative content clause as its complement. "Then" is anaphoric here to some previously mentioned event or time, where the meaning is "after that".

Answer (score 1):

In this case *then* is operating as an [adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then) (Merriam-Webster), denoting that the action in the sentence has occurred at that time or after another action in a sequence:

> : at that time
>
> : following next after in order of position, narration, or enumeration : being next in a series

In this case its function as an adverb rather than a conjunction can be tested by changing the position of *then* to the end of the sentence or other positions. In these cases, the expression is still syntactically valid:

> The staff **then** assembled the units.
>
> The staff assembled the units **then**.

A [subordinate conjunction](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/conjunctions.htm) has to stay in position at the start of its clause. Here's an illustration with **because**:

> The event happened **because** the staff assembled the units

but not

> :( The event happened the staff assembled the units **because**.

Comment: Let's say I frame the sentence as "The customer ordered, then the staff assembled the units". Now, "then" acts as a subordinate conjunction. Will the sentence "then the staff assembled the units" still be called an independent clause in the above sentence?

Comment: In "Then the staff assembled the units," *then* functions as a conjunctive adverb at the start of the independent clause, not a subordinate conjunction. In "The customer ordered, then the staff assembled the units," the sentence is a run-on unless a coordinating conjunction is also provided or elided to connect the two independent clauses: "The customer ordered, (and) then the staff assembled the units."

Comment: So, how can I identify when is "then" used as subordinate conjunction in a sentence? Because @Robusto in comments gave a sentence in which "then" was used as subordinate conjunction but in my sentence, it is not.

Comment: I don't think Robusto's example uses a subordinate conjunction, since the "subordinate clause" is an independent clause when taken in isolation, and so must be an independent clause in the larger sentence. AFAIK what you ask is not possible.